# How to recover deleted project root directory?

Tags: git, git-checkout

I've deleted my main directory by mistake. This is the directory where I created my Git repository.

I'm trying to recover files with `git checkout`, but it's showing

```
fatal error: not a git repo: .git
```

Comment: Did you push your work anywhere else? Normally all of Git's history is stored in a hidden `.git/` directory in your repository root. If you deleted the folder you deleted the history. Though some tools keep the repository elsewhere (e.g. I think EGit and tools based on it do). What client are you using?

Comment: no @Chris, i didn't pushed anywhere else. i'm using windows 10

Comment: Which IDE are you using, if any?

Comment: If you didn't push anywhere, why did you tag this question with the github tag?

Comment: @RobinGreen no, i'm not using any IDE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In most cases¹ your repository will be stored in a hidden `.git/` directory in the root of your repository, e.g.

- `project_root/`

  - `.git/` ← All of your history is here
  - `project_file.json`
  - …

By deleting `project_root/` you have also deleted all of your project's history. If you had pushed your project to a remote like GitLab or GitHub you'd be able to get (at least some of) it back using `git clone`.

But since you haven't pushed your code anywhere your only options are things that live outside of the Git ecosystem, e.g.:

- OS-level backups
- OS-level filesystem snapshots
- Dropbox or other file synchronization tools that remember multiple versions

---

¹Some tools store the repository outside of the project directory. The most notable example is EGit. If you are using an EGit-based tool (e.g. Eclipse or GitEye) you may be able to recover your working directory.